# Importance of (the number of) ultrafilters

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

I have seen a proof about the numbers of ultrafilters in topology, namely a theorem of Pospíšil stating that there are $2^{2^\kappa}$ ultrafilters on every infinite set $X$ with $\kappa = |X|$.

The number of principal ultrafilters (the only one that can be constructed explicity) is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$, giving a lower bound the the number of ultrafilters.

So, the theorem of Pospíšil states how many different choices are available when using the axiom of choice. Why is this quantification of "maximal filters" (using Zorn for getting an ultrafilter) of interest in particular in connection with compactness?

My idea was the following:
An equivalent definition of compactness is that all universal nets converge and universal nets are equivalent to ultrafilters. The number of ultrafilters hence give me another argument to see why nets are needed and sequences do not suffice in non-metric spaces.
So, can this theorem be seen how big one have to choose the set the net is defined on in order to find a full description of the space? How are those properties called?

Comment: The number of principal ultrafilters on $X$ is the cardinality of $X$, not of $\mathbb N$ (unless you were assuming that $\kappa=\aleph_0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows how large a compactification can be. If we have a discrete space $D$ of size $\kappa$ and $X$ is a compactification of $D$ (so that $X$ is compact Hausdorff and has $D$ as a dense subset), the largest that $X$ can be $2^{2^\kappa}$, namely when every ultrafilter on $D$ ( which must have a limit in $X$), gets a different limit. So we then need $2^{2^\kappa}$ many new points outside $D$.

It is well known that $w(X) \le 2^{d(X)}$ for $T_3$ spaces and $|X| \le 2^{w(X)}$ for $T_0$ spaces. So the Čech-Stone compactification (hence the number of ultrafilters) shows these bounds cannot be improved upon.